# Can we list all the *.[c,h,S] files that are used by "make" command to build the linux kernel?

Tags: build, linux-kernel, makefile

There are a lot of files in the kernel source that are not used most of the times. I wanted to list out only the files that are compiled when I issue a make command.

I thought that only those files that will be compiled are accessed during a make and hence, I tried the following command :

> find . -type f -name *.[chS] -anewer Makefile

But I found that many files that are not a part of the required architecture are also being accessed. Please suggest a method in which I could list those filenames along with their path form the kernel source top directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `make cscope` and then check out the file list in the `cscope.files` plaintext file. You need the cscope tool installed on your system.

Comment: That was a very simple and elegant solution! Thanks :)